# Inconsistency regarding questions

Tags: bug, questions

On WPSE, I noticed several times on several days some inconsistencies regarding the questions. Sometimes I don't see any question (no matter what tab I'm on). Now I discovered a somewhat more buggy behavior, illustrated in this screenshot:

[image: Inconsistency]

There definitely **are** featured questions (namely **3**) as indicated in the tab, however, the *content* and the *question counter* think differently.

Why is that?

Comment: Are you still experiencing this? Cannot reproduce (as in I see three questions and counter correctly).

Comment: @Rarst No, I cannot reproduce this as _at will_. It just happens out of nowhere, and after I have clicked some tabs (which all show no single question) I eventually can see the questions again (on a tab that I clicked before!). After that, all is working as expected - until some other day when it happens again.

Comment: I do not recall ever seeing this behavior.

Comment: It's the various caching mechanisms.  Do a hard refresh or wait a few minutes and they should be back in sync.